# Ediiting xml node value in my xml file in res/raw folder(Android)

Tags: android, xml, domparser

I am new to Android. I have been trying to update a node value of my xml file using DomParser. I have been workin with asset folder xml file to read. I realised asset folder files cannot be updated and then created a raw folder to save my xml file.I have been refering many answers provided by different people for a long time but nothing is workin!

Portion of my .xml file

```
<events>
   <type>ABC</type>
   <time>1:30-2:45pm</time>
   <day>XYX</day>
   <note>123</note>
</events>
```

and I have been trying the code

```
try{
 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(temp1);
 Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
 if (null != doc.getDocumentElement()){

            v1.setText("\n\nhiii888",doc.getDocumentElement());    ("HERE")
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
            layout.addView(v1);
        }
 Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("events").item(0);

 NodeList list = nodes.getChildNodes();

 for (int i =0; i<list.getLength();i++){
     Node node = list.item(i);


     if("type".equals(nodes.getNodeName())){
         node.setNodeValue("ABC123");
     }
   }
         TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
         StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("temp1.xml"));
         transformer.transform(source, result);


     }
```

My app shows stopped running when executing this and so I put in the piece of ***if block*** with textview and relative layout("mentioned as "HERE") to see where until the code works fine..The getDocumentElement()does return a value and so it displays in textview as

```
 hiii888org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl@e58aa2f
```

I dont know why this is coming.I also used Text to typecast and retrieve the result and also .toString() function expecting typecasting can solve the problem.Nothing seem to work..Have been trying Xml update now for days...Hope to see answers that can sort my issue regarding xml update other than the already existing ones...Thanks in advance.